# Why Android WebView does not display properly HTML page with Hebrew text when text-align set to "justify"

Tags: android, android-webview, hebrew, text-align, text-justify

I want to display local html file on a WebView. (Android 2.3.3)

The HTML contains Hebrew text. I want the text to be justified, so in my css file I do the following:

```
body
{ 
    text-align: justify; direction: rtl;
}
```

But for some reason the text end up being messed up:
[image: Text aligned to left...]

And this is definitely not "justified" but more aligned to the left.

Any idea how can overcome this problem?
It's working perfectly fine on any other browser than the WebView. (Including WebKit based ones)

Comment: I would appreciate it if could publish a solution if you find one.

Comment: Trust me I will... But i can't find one! I hoped it will be solved in Ice Cream Sandwich

Comment: Form the text you put here I can see that all you need is simple text.
I solved the alignment problem by using TextView.
I get the string from the web, and then 
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));

Comment: No, Actually I have some JavaScript going on, so I have to use a WebView.
But Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{   
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);   

     WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);        
     WebSettings settings = myWebView.getSettings(); 
     settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8"); 

     String webtext = "שלום";
String summary = "<html lang=\"he\"><body><p dir=\"rtl\">" + webtext + "</p></body></html>";
    myWebView.loadData(summary, "text/html", null); 

}
```